# C++: Upload large file to Azure using multiple threads with integrity check

Tags: c++, multithreading, azure, cloud

My goal is to upload a file in Azure with integrity check and using multiple threads using C++. There is 2 function which I found in azure sdk to upload data.

`Upload` - which receives `UploadBlockBlobOptions` as optional parameter. This structure has a field `Azure::Nullable<ContentHash> TransactionalContentHash` which is hash of the blob content. This hash is used to verify the integrity of the blob during transport. When this header is specified, the storage service checks the hash that has arrived with the one that was sent.

`UploadBlockBlobFromOptions` - which has `UploadBlockBlobFromOptions` as optional parameter. This one contains a structure `TransferOptions` which has a field `Concurrency`. The number of threads that may be used in a parallel transfer. So I'm guessing this number will be used to create multiple threads and upload a file in parallel.

Is there any function or maybe someone can give me direction of how can I have both integrity check of a file and also upload it with multiple threads?